# Unidirectional Navigation Properties

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Is there anyway to make EF navigational properties unidirectional?

In the example below, I would like to remove "Customers" property from the "Orders" table.

Driver behind this is the "circular reference" error I am receiving with Telerik Grid (which tries to serialize my object for Ajax Binding).

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also run into this. Telerik has an article describing the problem and the solution http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/10-01-25/resolving_circular_references_when_binding_the_mvc_grid.aspx

Basically instead of deleting the property, as @Akhil suggests, you set it to Private which feels a little less destructive.

Comment: Thanks for the pointing it out. It seems to work. However, after trying it out, I've decided that I don't really need AJAX binding. I'll stick to server binding for now. :-)

Comment: Also one of the options they point out. BTW I've found projecting the data for the grid into a viewmodel and basing the grid on that to be my default solution

Answer (score 0):

**If its EF4,**

Just Click on "`Customers`" Navigational Property in the Model View, and `Delete` (right click & delete).

**If Its Earlier Versions,**

You cannot do this in the edm-designer. You have to go into the xml-code and look for the navigationproperty you dont want to have and remove it.  You will find the navigationiproperty in the CSDL area of your xml-code.

Comment: I've tried deleting the property, however, for some reason, the circular reference error still exists.